# How to separate source file from all vendors in webpack?

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack

I want to have two files `app.bundle.js` and `vendors.js` where `app.bundle.js` contains **only** the code I wrote. Is it possible?

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file now

```
const dependencies = _.keys(packageConfig["dependencies"])

export default {
    entry: {
        vendors: dependencies,
        app: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
            './src/js/entry.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    ...

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
        ...
```

But it does not work. I always had an error when compiling because some modules are not found. I've tried to list all dependencies manually, but in such case I have third party code in my `app.bundle.js`. So is it even possible?

**UPDATE**

I've take a look into the compiled `app.bundle.js` and saw code from hot replacement module and webpack itself. So the real question is - is this a default code that have to be placed inside each webpack module?

**UPDATE**

My first line in the entry file is `import 'babel-core/polyfill'` so I want module `babel-core` to be in `vendors.js`. And have this error

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-core/~/regenerator/lib/visit.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/vitalii/Documents/coding/timerrrs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/regenerator/lib
 @ ./~/babel-core/~/regenerator/lib/visit.js 12:9-22

ERROR in ./~/babel-core/~/regexpu/data/iu-mappings.json
Module parse failed: /Users/vitalii/Documents/coding/timerrrs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/regexpu/data/iu-mappings.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "75": 8490,
|   "83": 383,
|   "107": 8490,
 @ ./~/babel-core/~/regexpu/rewrite-pattern.js 4:17-51

ERROR in ./~/babel-core/~/globals/globals.json
Module parse failed: /Users/vitalii/Documents/coding/timerrrs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/globals/globals.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "builtin": {
|       "Array": false,
|       "ArrayBuffer": false,
 @ ./~/babel-core/~/globals/index.js 1:17-42

ERROR in ./~/babel-core/~/regenerator/~/recast/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/vitalii/Documents/coding/timerrrs/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/regenerator/node_modules/recast
 @ ./~/babel-core/~/regenerator/~/recast/main.js 18:4-17
```

Comment: ```vendor: dependencies``` but ```CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors'``` - is this a typo (I mean *vendor* vs. *vendors*)?

Comment: sorry, this was typo when posting this question. It's OK in real webpack config

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Take a look at *index.js* inside *babel-core* package: ```module.exports = require("./lib/api/node.js");```. So it require node.js module - not for build with. You can specify module this way: ```module.exports = require("babel-core/lib/api/browser.js");```

Comment: Better idea is to use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Comment: I want to stick with Babel 5 for now